# SQL update query with inner join optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have below SQL update query. I am working on MySQL

```
UPDATE stg_table AS stg
       INNER JOIN s_table AS s
               ON stg.s_name = s.s_name
                  AND stg.s_key = s.s_key
SET    update_ind = 1,
       stg.s_id = s.s_id,
       stg.m_id = s.m_id
WHERE  stg.processed_ind = 0
```

It is taking long time to process and because of that I am getting lock wait time out exception in Java.

Is it possible to optimize this query otherwise I will have to increase lock wait time on MySQL side?

**Note**: For now I am having 30k records in stg_table table and 3k records in s_table table.

For now I am having `innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50` as default value. If I increase the innodb_lock_wait_timeout to some larger value say 200 then my problem might get solve. But I am not sure if the data in the table increases then this query may result in the same situation. This is my point of view, please correct me if I am going wrong with my understanding

Comment: Don't really see any reason that query should take too long.  Do you have any indices on your tables?  Particular the `s_name` and `s_key` columns...

Comment: @sgeddes, I don't have indices for `s_name` and `s_key`. Note: `s_id` is primary key of `s_table` table.

Comment: @sgeddes, I added index over stg.s_name and stg.s_key and performance improved drastically. Now my query is taking 0.05 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added index over `stg.s_name` and `stg.s_key` and my problem got solved. Now my query is taking 0.05 seconds.